# Why does Kafka Connect treat timestamp columns differently?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, db2, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka Connect configuration set up to pull data from DB2. I'm not using Avro, just the out-of-the-box json. Among the colums in the db are several timestamp columns, and when they are streamed, they come out like this:

```
"Process_start_ts": 1578600031762,
"Process_end_ts": 1579268248183,
"created_ts": 1579268247984,
"updated_ts": {
 "long": 1579268248182
 }
}
```

The last column is rendered with this sub-element, though the other 3 are not. (This will present problems for the consumer.) 
The only thing I can see is that in the DB, that column alone has a default value of null.

[image]

Is there some way I can force this column to render in the message as the prior 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try to flatten your message using [Kafka Connect Transformations](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html#kconnect-long-transformations).

The configuration snippet below shows how to use [Flatten](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html) to concatenate field names with the period `.` delimiter character (you have to add these lines to the connector config):

```
"transforms": "flatten",
"transforms.flatten.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
"transforms.flatten.delimiter": "."
```

As a result, your JSON message should look like this:

```
{
  "Process_start_ts": 1578600031762,
  "Process_end_ts": 1579268248183,
  "created_ts": 1579268247984,
  "updated_ts.long": 1579268248182
}
```

See [example](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html#json-example) Flatten SMT for JSON.

Comment: The updated time is an Avro nullable long, not a nested struct

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `created` is any different than the first two. The value is still a long, only the key is all lower case. It's not clear how it would know what the default should be - are you using sure you're not using AvroConverter? If not, it's not clear what fields would have defaults

The updated time is nested like that, based on the Avro or structured JSON Kafka Connect specifications that say the type name is included as part of the record to explicitly denote the type of a nullable field

Comment: I haven't specified any schema for the messages. I assume Kafka Connect is inferring it from the data. The Flatten SMT, btw, had no effect.

Comment: The JDBC Source connector creates the Schema. The record is already flat, so not sure what you expected, and I never told you to use that

Comment: Sorry, it was the other answer that suggested the flatten. When you say the record is already flat, not following. The record still contains the sub-element:

"created_ts": 1579268247984,
"updated_ts": {
 "long": 1579268248182
 }

Comment: Right. Like I said in the comments there, the record is not a nested struct. It is a nullable long field, so therefore the type is necessary, as documented in the Avro specification

Comment: If you remove any NULL field inside the database for `updated_ts`, then you would have a "cleaner" schema. Otherwise, there is nothing inheritently wrong with it. You should use an Avro schema parser, not a JSON parser to handle it